# Deploying spinnaker using halyard on Kubernetes

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

Trying to deploy spinnaker in Kubernetes using halyard.
All my custom configurations are under

> ~/.hal/default/service-settings
>
> ~/.hal/default/profile

So, running the below command deploys the configuration.

> hal deploy apply

This reads my settings under default. Is it possible to have a folder other than default? if so, How can i change the config to use the config under the new folder as opposed to default.

Also, All the pods are using the test & local profiles while starting.

```
com.netflix.spinnaker.front50.Main       : The following profiles are active: test,local
```

Is this only for test or local deployment? Is there any production profile for production grade spinnaker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the "default", this is called "Deployment" - see this: https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/halyard/#deployments

And, on the profile names, I would not worry too much... You add overrides to the "profiles" directory on these...